# How to validate checkbox in Angular 6 using reactive form validation

Tags: angular6, angular7

How to validate checkboxes for at least one selected error message. I tried, but it's not working. [Link to my project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6tqrmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

app.component:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
<label formArrayName="orders" *ngFor="let order of orders; let i = index">
<input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
{{order[i].name}}
</label>

<div *ngIf="???">At least one order must be selected</div>
<br>
<button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Fix your stackblitz errors , that code has some erros/dependencies issue

Comment: @AmitGolhar:   Can you resolve it?

Comment: Seems you are using twp template-driven strategy and reactive strategy together. Use one strategy